# "Implanting" a windows form into another executable? (Visual Basic 10)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

Mostly this is a theory question not really a practical one. I'll admit the only real use I see for this would be some sort of virus. (:

EDIT 3:
Thought of a use for this. Easy simplification of companion programs I.E. chat programs, clipboard, etc. Also, you could have a transparent, noborder, location locked notification program on top of a fullscreen application. (: Get notices about email while playing MW2 or whatever.

Is it possible to program something in VB to "implant" a windows form into an existing application? So say whenever I open my office program a windows form I made comes up in addition to the office program (without changing how the other app functions) and possibly independent of the office program (when one is closed the other remains).
I have a project with a windows form, it's just a form with 2 text boxes, a label, a progress bar, a button, and a timer, we'll call this program A.
Program B is a basic word processor program (word pad, works writer, etc). Program C is the implanting program.

EDIT: Programs A and C are visual basic applications. Program B is any given windows program.

When program C runs it takes a copy of program A and finds program B. It implants program A into program B and then quits. Then when program B launches, there is no difference in program B's functionality, but an extra windows form (program A) launches simultaneously to program B. When looking at the task manager the user sees one process, program B's process. Finally, if the user re-runs program C it finds program B again and removes program A.

EDIT 2: My actual question is can you give me some code examples or theory help for program C, the implant/remove program.

Any thoughts?

Brian

Side note:  I assure you nervous types this is merely for learning.

Comment: Yes, is a virus :) but what are you asking here?? You will have a problem if the .exe is signed, but beside that, it "should" work..

Comment: Oh I didn't actually ask my question did I?
Can anyone give me VB code examples for program C?
And signed? What does that mean again? random mind-blank

Comment: You can sign the assembly, so if you change it, it will not work.. something like an antivirus protection ;).

Comment: ah yes. So if program B is signed it will fail. I would expect that. Anyone have example code for C? and could A and C possibly be one program?

Comment: To get better (any) answers, make sure you try something on your own first. This isn't Google, nor is it RepositoryOfDevelopersWithFreeTimeToBuildYourIdeaForFree.com. Show us what you got and then we can help you with specific problems. And welcome to SO! :)

Comment: Ok, I'll edit it to include the research I did, thanks for the advice.

Comment: @BrianBTB I don't think any antivirus would like your idea, however you could achieve a similar result by dll injection.